# Parametrizing TOP value in tsql and pyodbc

Tags: python, t-sql, pyodbc

I try to parametrize number of top rows to get from table.

I tried it with

```
db.cursor.execute(
        '''
        SELECT TOP ? VALUE FROM mytable 
        WHERE param = ? 
        ''',
        top_value, param
    )
```

and it showed

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17
>   for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '@P1'. (102)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)")

with string interpolation like bellow it works.

```
    db.cursor.execute(
        f'''
        SELECT TOP {top_limit} VALUE FROM mytable 
        WHERE SITE_SK_FK = ? 
        ''',
        param
    )
```

Do I need to pass it as parameter, or string interpolation is good enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parameterize `top` by surrounding the value with parenthesis:

```sql
DECLARE @Top int = 5;

With Tally(N) AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID)
    FROM sys.objects
)

-- This works just fine
SELECT TOP (@Top) N
FROM Tally;

-- This will raise an error: Incorrect syntax near '@Top'
SELECT TOP @Top N 
FROM Tally;
```

Applied to the code you've posted:

```sql
SELECT TOP (?) VALUE 
FROM mytable 
WHERE param = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting for the TOP (and a proper parameter for the WHERE) provided that `top_limit` is an `int` so there is very little danger of SQL Injection issues.

Comment: I know nothing about python, but Jon Skeet once wrote a blog post called [The Bobby Tables culture](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/08/the-bobbytables-culture/) - which is a good read if you think numbers are safe.